# A kind of uniqueness for the double of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be two manifolds with the same boundary. If their doubles $D(M)$ and $D(N)$ are diffeomorphic, are $M$ and $N$ diffeomorphic?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you may be interested in [Mazur manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold). A Mazur manifold is a smooth four-dimensional manifold with boundary which is not diffeomorphic to the standard four-dimensional ball $B^4$, but it's double is $S^4$ (as is the ball's). This doesn't provide a counterexample necessarily as the boundary of a Mazur manifold doesn't have to be $S^3 = \partial B^4$, but it does have to be a homology three-sphere (i.e. the homology groups of the boundary of a Mazur manifold are the same as the homology groups of $S^3$).

Comment: I'll just point out that one should impose connectedness, as there are uninteresting (disconnected) counter examples in $2$ dimensions. Take for instance $M=D^2\sqcup D^2\sqcup\Sigma^2$ and $N=S^2\sqcup (T^2\setminus D^2) \sqcup (T^2\setminus D^2)$. Then the boundaries are two circles for both $M$ and $N$, and the doubles are both diffeomorphic to the disjoint union of two $2$-spheres and two genus $2$ surfaces $\Sigma^2$.